# Wordpress wp_editor shortcode issue

Tags: wordpress

I have created a front-end editor using wp_editor that functions as it should.

Upon testing I have noticed that it is stripping out any shortcodes that have been inserted in the content. I have looked into this issue and found that it's the 'ob_' (output buffering) that is removing them. If I remove this output buffering then the shortcodes display fine, but it breaks the functionality I have created for the editor.

How would I keep the code I am using below, but amend it to make sure that all shortcodes are being displayed? Any help/ideas greatly appreciated, S.

```
if(!is_feed() && current_user_can( 'manage_network' ) ) :

function ps_add_post_editor($content) {
global $post;
$settings = array(
    'wpautop' => true,
    'media_buttons' => false
);
    $content .= '<div id="content-edit-area" style="display:none;"><form action="" id="page-content-editor-panel" method="post"><span id="ajax_my_post_edit_nonce" class="hidden">' . wp_create_nonce( 'ajax_my_post_edit_nonce' ) . '</span>' . ps_get_wp_editor($post->post_content, 'textarea-' . $post->ID , $settings) . '<input type="submit" id="feesavebtn" value="Save" /></form><a href="#" id="cancelbtn">Cancel</a></div><br><br><div id="loadingmessage"><img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/loading.gif" /> saving...</div>

    <style type="text/css">
        #textarea-'.$post->ID.'_ifr, #textarea-'.$post->ID.' { min-height:700px !important; }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(\'#page-content-editor-panel\').submit(function(){       
    var pageid = '.$post->ID.'; 
    var content;
    var editor = tinyMCE.get(\'textarea-'.$post->ID.'\');
    if (editor) {
        content = editor.getContent();
    } else {
        content = jQuery(\'#textarea-'.$post->ID.'\').val();
    }       
    jQuery(\'#content-edit-area\').hide();  
    jQuery(\'#loadingmessage\').show(); 
    jQuery.post(
       ajaxurl, 
       {
          \'action\':\'add_foobar\',
          \'nonce\':jQuery(\'#ajax_my_post_edit_nonce\').text(),
          \'post_id\':pageid,
          \'post_data\':content
       }, 
       function(response){            
          window.location.reload(true); 
       }
    ); 
    return false;        
    });
    </script>';

return $content;
}

function ps_get_wp_editor($content,$textarea,$settings) {
ob_start();
wp_editor($content, $textarea, $settings);
$edior_html_code = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $edior_html_code;
} 
add_filter('the_content', 'ps_add_post_editor');

add_action('wp_ajax_add_foobar', 'prefix_ajax_add_foobar');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_foobar', 'prefix_ajax_add_foobar');

function prefix_ajax_add_foobar() {
if( wp_verify_nonce( $_REQUEST['nonce'], 'ajax_my_post_edit_nonce' ) )           {      
    $myfee_post = array();
    $myfee_post['ID'] = $_POST['post_id'];
    $myfee_post['post_content'] = $_POST['post_data'];
    wp_update_post( $myfee_post );      
    die("This page has now been updated."); 
} else {        
    die("Unable to process your request at this time.");
}
}

endif;
```

Comment: I don't know if you've already come across this but it may be of <i>vague</i> use https://github.com/jaredatch/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress/issues/129. I've had so many issues with Ajax and this `wp_editor` function that have remained unresolved and information is very scarce.

Comment: I tested your code using `wp_editor()` instead of `ps_get_wp_editor()` (no `ob_*` stuff) and it works ok, the shortcodes are not stripped. Did you try disabling all other plugins and using TwentyTwelve theme?

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit, I'm not entirely sure what your goal is, but for what it's worth this seems to work for me:

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'do_shortcode', 11);

function ps_get_wp_editor($content,$textarea,$settings = array()) {
   ob_start();
   wp_editor($content, $textarea, $settings);
   $editor_html_code = ob_get_contents();
   ob_end_clean();
   return $editor_html_code;
}

function ps_add_post_editor($content) {
    global $post;

    $post_content = $post->post_content;
    $content = ps_get_wp_editor($post_content, 'ps-editor-' . $post->ID );
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'ps_add_post_editor');

function ps_eat_pants() {
    return "eat pants has happened";
}
add_shortcode('eat_pants', 'ps_eat_pants');
```

The thing is, if you want to be able to EDIT The shortcode as it was in the editor on the back end, you need to remove the 'do_shortcode' filter from 'the_content' so that it doesn't run when displayed on the front end.

I have to admit, I have no idea how the code you posted actually worked, I'm assuming that it was either mistyped or out of context. =)

I mean, there was no point at which you were actually giving your function all necessary parameters...

It might help if you explained what you were doing in greater detail, but I hope this helps.

[EDIT: Oh, and that "eat_pants" thing is just a test shortcode...]

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply - removing the shortcode filter did fix my problem, but when saving or cancelling the edit, the shortcodes were left as code rather than being run. (I have added my full code above).

Comment: @ss888 Oh, well, I think you'll have to find some condition during which you can remove and re-add that filter. You'll have to somehow re-add the filter when you're displaying the posts, and only remove it when adding the editor... 

Hrrm... that might be tricky. I'm wondering if you could only remove do_shortcode from the the_content filter when you're adding in the editor somehow, but I'm a little stumped at the moment. It's tricky because "the_content" will always be filtered on the front end, and that's where you want to display the inline editor...

Comment: aarrrrgggghhhhh!!!! thanks for the information - can't seem to find any way of making this work!!!!!